# Tomcat and acceptCount not working

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

I am using tomcat 8 as part of Spring Boot project and my acceptCount setting seems to be not working. Instead of only accepting 300 connections, my server accepted almost 1000 connection I threw at it, though of course processing no more than 200 of them simultaneously.

Tomcat documentation seems to be clear on acceptCount: "The maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use. Any requests received when the queue is full will be refused." But clearly that does not happen.

There is of course another setting, maxConnections, and its documentation says: "Note that once the limit has been reached, the operating system may still accept connections based on the acceptCount setting" - but that note alone does not yet mean acceptCount is "count on top of maxConnections, not maxThreads" (like the topicstarter at https://coderanch.com/t/647733/application-servers/Tomcat-BIO-connector-configurations thinks). It just means that it will have its effect in both cases: when all processing threads are busy, and when all available connections are exhausted. (And even if that guy was correct, that would mean Tomcat documentation is outright wrong when defining acceptCount...)

Then why is it ignored? I found some mentions of discussions where people supposedly claimed that acceptCount does not work for them, but did not find actual discussions :( Even on the contrary, I was able to find some complains about how Tomcat chokes after 300 connections (which is exactly default maxThreads + acceptCount). So I can see that for some people it works, and I am asked to believe that "maybe" for some people it does not. Not for me either. Should I trust that the Tomcat manual is wrong in a sense that this option is not always respected?

Comment: BTW, how I detected that the connection was accepted. I used curl to send requests (many instances of curl executed in parallel) in verbose mode, and counted how many of them reported that connection has been made. Most of them even reported sending a request, but of course we can't be sure if they meant just starting sending, or actually finishing pushing request body into a socked.

Comment: Post your effective configuration, and explain your testing methodology.

Comment: I gave some more details on that in my comments below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are complicated relationships between all of these settings, and they are further complicated by your choice of connector (e.g. BIO, NIO, APR, etc.).

The BIO connector is essentially dead... it does not exist past Tomcat 8.0.x. It cannot accept any more connections than the thread pool can process at a time. Therefore, the BIO connector essentially makes `maxConnections == maxThreads`. Therefore, for a BIO connector, the number of connections the server is willing to accept should be `maxConnections` + `acceptCount`, but `maxConnections` is limited to some relatively small number.

The other connectors, which are more complicated, allow more than one connection per thread to be *accepted* in the TCP/IP sense.The defaults for `maxConnections` are closer to 10k (varies by exact type), and the thread pool size is not relevant, so the number of connections the server is willing to accept is `maxConnections` + `acceptCount`.

The reason the non-BIO connectors can accept so many more connections is because the two states where an active request-processing thread are not necessary (waiting for the next HTTP-keepalive-request - using `read()` and waiting for the next connection - using `accept()`) are done by a separate thread, allowing the request-processing thread to go back into the pool as quickly as possible in order to service other requests.

If you are using BIO, I'd expect connections to fail after e.g. 300 connections (you didn't post your configuration, so it's impossible to say what the actual numbers would be) but for NIO, I'd expect it to be north of 10k connections.

For testing, it's important that you don't actually do anything with your connection in order to count them properly. Basically, you need to do this:

```
foreach(i from 0..10301)
    conn[i] = connect('host:port')
```

You should find that there is some `i` for which the server will not accept the connection. If you connect and issue `GET /` then the server will respond and the connection *and* the request-processing thread will go back into their respective pools.

** UPDATE after reading some comments**

I'd expect to be able to simultaneously-process 200 requests, but Tomcat will happily queue another 800 requests internally. The additional 200 in the `acceptQueue` are being queued by the OS's TCP/IP stack, not by Tomcat/Java

Assuming infinite read-timeouts on the clients, I'd expect you to be able to launch 1201 instances of `curl` where the first 200 in the door immediately get a thread (and sleep), the next 800 get queued in Tomcat/Java, the next 200 get queued in the TCP/IP stack, and instance #1201 gets a "connection refused" response.

Once the first set of 200 requests are completed, Tomcat will process another batch of 200 requests, the 200 connections in the TCP/IP queue will move from that queue into the Tomcat/Java queue, and after 20 seconds the second set of 200 requests will complete. That will repeat until all 1200 of the initial requests return a response to their clients. Only 1 of the 1200 requests will be refused.

Comment: Well, I was speaking of NIO connectors, and I am generally aware of the way NIO works, though thanks for explanation you provided. Problem is, "I'd expect it to be north of 10k connections" is OK but there are some definitions in the manual, let me repeat my quote: acceptCount="maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use." Even if server is capable of serving 10000 connections, it can only serve maxThreads=200 request at a time; add acceptCount=100 and expect it to block on 300th incoming connection.

Comment: "If you connect and issue GET / then the server will respond" - I do that; I also do Thread.sleep(20000) on server side before responding, blocking the processing thread for 20 seconds. And, I used for + curl + & to make 1000 parallel requests, of which almost all successfully connected and then eventually were served.

Comment: Christopher, but why you expect tomcat to queue another 800 connection requests after initial 200? Where did that figure come from? Also, that contradicts the manual: acceptCount=100 is the maximum queue length for incoming connection requests when all possible request processing threads are in use. According to that, tomcat or whoever else (tcp stack included) should not queue any connections beyond maxThreads+acceptCount=300, I hate to repeat that again :)

Comment: I totally share your understanding of *what* is happening (200 then 200 more etc.), I just fail to understand *why* that is happening. It should not, according to Tomcat docs.

Comment: What part of my explanation isn't inline with your understanding of the documentation?

Comment: Well, I just quoted again, maxThreads+acceptCount=300 should prevent tomcat from accepting 300th connection. Yet you think there is nothing wrong with "Tomcat will happily queue another 800 requests internally".

Comment: The `maxThreads` setting here is irrelevant. Only the `maxConnections` setting is, and the default there is 10,000. The expected number of accepted connections will be `maxConnections` + `acceptCount` = 10200. I have stated that clearly in my answer, and I'm sure you can test it out experimentally, but you choose to neither read nor believe. I don't believe I can help you understand any better.

Comment: You are saying it's irrelevant without explaining *why*. That does not really count as answer by me, rather a guess. I, on the other hand, quoted a reference manual, which says quite clearly that maxThreads participates in limiting number of accepted connections. So yes, I choose not to believe you unless you feel like dropping in some explanation.

Comment: And yes, I saw your statement that actual limit is maxConnections + acceptCount and you probably imply it just happened to be equal to maxThreads + acceptCount for BIO connectors, and that's why they wrote "maxThreads + acceptCount" in the manual. That may be the case, but 1) who can confirm it? 2) this still means the reference manual IS buggy *today* (when not only BIO is available)!

Comment: You may be right that the *introduction* section can mislead the reader; it appears to be leftover from the times where only BIO was supported. I'll try to get that corrected.

Comment: Thank you. Most probably you're right and the limit is maxConnections + acceptCount (since maxThreads as connection limit makes no sense for NIO). And I also think that Mark Thomas's answer should also be reflected in the manual, even if it's not the actual reason of going far above maxThreads+acceptCount.

Answer (score 1):

`acceptCount` for NIO is passed in to `ServerSocket.bind(SocketAddress,int)` as the 2nd parameter (backlog). The Javadoc for that method says:

> The backlog argument is the requested maximum number of
>   pending connections on the socket. Its exact semantics are implementation
>   specific. In particular, an implementation may impose a maximum length
>   or may choose to ignore the parameter altogether.

It looks like it is being ignored in your JVM.

Comment: Quite possible, thanks. But that suggests the reference manual is incomplete because it does not say that the parameter can be ignored.

Comment: Re-read the quote in this answer, specifically the last 7 words.

Comment: Why should I? You think I don't understand that this Javadoc says the parameter can be ignored? Well I do. But having a correct *Javadoc* does not mean the *reference manual* (which I quoted) does not have to be correct as well.

Comment: That's what I'm been looking for.